# Tengo un error al mostrar datos en un Grid

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-tool-suite

Estoy trabajando con **Java Spring**,**hibernate** y **maven** y al ver los datos de una grid me sale este error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 147704 of the JSON data.

Pero solo me sale cuando agrego datos en la tabla factura y no entiendo porque. alguien me podria ayudar

**Código de la tabla *Productos***

```
CREATE TABLE `Producto` (
  `IdProducto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Descripcion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Precio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdFactura` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdProducto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Este el código de la tabla de *Factura***

```
CREATE TABLE `Factura` (
  `IdFactura` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IdCliente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdProducto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CantidadProducto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdFactura`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Este es el controlador de *factura***

```
package com.csye.rooms.web.controller;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;

import com.csye.rooms.bo.ClienteBo;
import com.csye.rooms.bo.FacturaBo;
import com.csye.rooms.bo.JqGridBo;
import com.csye.rooms.bo.ProductosBo;
import com.csye.rooms.domain.Cliente;
import com.csye.rooms.domain.Factura;
import com.csye.rooms.domain.Productos;
import com.csye.rooms.utils.JqGridFilter;
import com.csye.rooms.utils.RespuestaService;
import com.csye.rooms.web.propertyEditor.ClientePropertyEditor;
import com.csye.rooms.web.propertyEditor.ProductosPropertyEditor;


@Controller
public class FacturaController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteBo                       clienteBo;

    @Autowired
    private ProductosBo                       productosBo;

    @Autowired
    private FacturaBo                       facturaBo;

    @Autowired
    private JqGridBo                                        jqGridBo;

//  @Autowired
//  private FacturaFormValidator                        facturaFormValidator;

    @Autowired
    private ClientePropertyEditor                   clientePropertyEditor;

    @Autowired
    private ProductosPropertyEditor productosPropertyEditor;


    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Collection.class, "productos", productosPropertyEditor);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Cliente.class, clientePropertyEditor);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ListarFactura.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listar(ModelMap model) {
        return "views/Factura/ListarFacturaForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ListarFacturaAjax.do", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    RespuestaService listarAjax(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        JqGridFilter delimitadores = new JqGridFilter(request, "Factura");
        Long total = jqGridBo.contar(delimitadores);
        Collection<Object> objetos = jqGridBo.listar(delimitadores);

        RespuestaService respuestaService = new RespuestaService();
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = objetos.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Factura object = (Factura) iterator.next();
            respuestaService.getRows().add(object);
        }
        respuestaService.setTotal(delimitadores.calculaCantidadPaginas(total));
        respuestaService.setPage(delimitadores.getPagina());
        respuestaService.setRecords(total);
        return respuestaService;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/AgregarFactura.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String agregarFactura(ModelMap model) {
        Factura factura = new Factura();
        factura.setCliente(new Cliente());
        model.addAttribute(new Factura());
        this.cargarListaClientes(model);
        this.cargarListaProductos(model, null, Boolean.FALSE);
        return "views/Factura/AgregarFacturaForm";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/CrearFactura.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String crearFactura(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Factura factura, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                this.cargarListaClientes(model);
                this.cargarListaProductos(model, factura, Boolean.FALSE);
                return "views/Factura/AgregarFacturaForm";
            } else {
                status.setComplete();
                facturaBo.incluir(factura);
                return "redirect:ListarFactura.do";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ModificarFactura.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String modificarFactura(ModelMap model, @RequestParam("id") Long idFactura) {
        Factura factura = facturaBo.obtener(idFactura);
            model.addAttribute(facturaBo.obtener(idFactura));
            this.cargarListaClientes(model);
        this.cargarListaProductos(model, factura, Boolean.TRUE);
            return "views/Factura/ModificarFacturaForm";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ActualizarFactura.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String actualizarFactura(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Factura factura, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
            this.cargarListaClientes(model);
            this.cargarListaProductos(model, factura, Boolean.TRUE);
                return "views/Factura/ModificarFacturaForm";
            } else {
                status.setComplete();
                facturaBo.modificar(factura);
                return "redirect:ListarFactura.do";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/EliminarFactura.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String borrarFactura(@RequestParam("id") Long idFactura) throws Exception {
        try {
            facturaBo.eliminar(facturaBo.obtener(idFactura));
            return "redirect:ListarFactura.do";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/MostrarFactura.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ceder(ModelMap model, @RequestParam("id") Long idFactura) {
        model.addAttribute("factura", facturaBo.obtener(idFactura));
        return "views/Factura/MostrarFacturaForm";
    }


    public void cargarListaClientes(ModelMap model) {
        Collection<Cliente> clientes = clienteBo.Listar();
        if (clientes != null && clientes.size() > 0) {
            model.addAttribute("clientes", clientes);
        }
    }

    public void cargarListaProductos(ModelMap model, Factura factura, Boolean eliminar) {
        Collection<Productos> productos = productosBo.listar();
        if (productos != null && productos.size() > 0) {
            if (eliminar) {
                productos.removeAll(factura.getProductos());
            }
            model.addAttribute("productos", productos);
        }
    }
}
```

**Este es el grid de *factura***

```
$("#gridFacturas").jqGrid({
        url: "ListarFacturaAjax.do",
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader : {
          root: "rows",
          page: "page",
          total: "total",
          records: "records",
        },              
        colNames: ["Cliente", "Producto", "Cantidad", "Total","Opciones"],
        colModel: [

            { name: "cliente.id", width:100, align:'center', searchrules:{required:true}, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}},
            { name: "productos.descripcion", width:170, align:'center', searchrules:{required:true}, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}},
            { name: "cantidadProducto", width:170, align:'center', searchrules:{required:true}, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}},
            { name: "total", width:170, align:'center', searchrules:{required:true}, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','cn']}},
            { name: "id", width:200,sortable:false, search:false, align:'center', 
                edittype:'select', formatter:linksFactura}, 
        ]
    }).navGrid('#paginacion');

    function linksFactura(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        var mostrar = '<a href = "MostrarFactura.do?id=' + options.rowId + '" class="mostrar" title="Mostrar"/>';
        var edit = '<a href = "ModificarFactura.do?id=' + options.rowId + '" class="edit" title="Editar"/>';
        var borrar = '<a href = "EliminarFactura.do?id=' + options.rowId 
        + '" onclick="return confirm(\'Est\u00E1 seguro que desea eliminar la factura seleccionada\');" class="borrar" title="Eliminar"/>'; 
        acciones = mostrar + edit+ borrar;      
        return acciones;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que uses los **[kendo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo)**, puedes hacer tablas de una manera muy sencilla, con los datos en formato [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) y datos en [Array](http://php.net/manual/es/book.array.php), además puedes tratar muy cómodamente el [DataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource).

Es una librería muy buena.

Referente a tu error, es porque no parseas bien el JSON, un formato JSON debe estar así:

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

Asegúrate de no tener un vector o un object, a mí me ha pasado :).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Disuclpa la ignorancia esque soy nuevo utilizando spring,hibernate y maven, donde puedo encontrar lo del JSON para verificar el formato¿?

Comment: Cualquier validador JSON

Comment: Bueno ya pude arreglar el problema aparantemente me faltaba una anotacion "@jsonIgnore".. de todas maneras muchas gracias ..